# Can Wordpress plugins "Talk to each other"?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Sorry if this is a really silly question, but I am very new to Word Press.

My question is, can one plugin update the settings of another Wordpress plugin? I suppose this might depend on the plugin and where it stores its settings. I don't know if plugins store their settings in static files or in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer would be yes.

It really depends on the plugin. A good plugin will take use of the many API's that Wordpress has set up for development, such as the settings API. Most plugins will probably store their settings using [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

A good place to start will be the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. So if I was to ask someone to develop a plugin for me, they could in theory get it to change settings for another plugin? It sounds like the answer is yes!

Comment: The answer is always yes, but how to do it will depend on the plugin.